# How to load aspx pages in tabcontainer

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax, tabcontrol

I am using tabcontainer control of Ajaxtoolkit.I want to load aspx page for each of the tabs asynchronously i.e when i click on tab at that time an aspx page should be loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Iframe and set `src="About.aspx"`

```
<iframe src="About.aspx"></iframe>
```

Check for details http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use this in 'Source' view of web page,
Exactly in here...like this way...

```
            <iframe src="Default2.aspx"></iframe>

          </ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how to dynamically set scr attribute of the ifram?